# WPF UserControl- pre-Load UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, powerpoint

I have a MainWindow and 4 UserControls. By switching the DataContext to my UserControls I can have an application with multiple "Pages". In every UserControl I have a webBrowser-Control that Displays an PowerPoint (so -> 4 UC = 4 ppt). The issue I have now is that when I Switch my DataContext (Switch Page) I have to load (call the navigate Method) the whole ppt in my webBrowser again and that takes some Time. How can I fix this?

thanks in advance :))

Adrian

**EDIT CODE**

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="Page1Template" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:Page1Model}" >
        <views:Page1 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="Page2Template" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:Page2Model}">
        <views:Page2 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="Page3Template" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:Page3Model}">
        <views:Page3 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="Page4Template" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:Page4Model}">
        <views:Page4 DataContext="{Binding}"/>    
</Window.Resources>
```

// ...

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}"></ContentControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs (i call the page Switch like this)

```
 private void menuBtn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {   
    DataContext = new Page1Model();   
 }
 private void menuBtn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    DataContext = new Page2Model();
 }
 private void menuBtn3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    DataContext = new Page3Model();
 }
 private void menuBtn4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    DataContext = new Page4Model();
 }
```

and lets say e.g my UserControl1: (when i call UC1 every time the ppt is opening again, i want just to open it one time):

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        powerPointBrowser1.Navigate("somePPTfile.pptx");
        powerPointBrowser1.LoadCompleted += powerPointBrowser1_LoadCompleted;
    }
```

i hope i made it clear :S

Comment: You can try like this, by preloading all the usercontrols as default on page load, after that you can make visibility `true` or `false` as per your respectives.

Comment: okay thanks and how can i do that? :D.  currently im working with a Content Control that Displays the Usercontrols in my MainWindow (Every UserControl has ist own ViewModel)

Comment: Can you share your code for the references, so that I can give you a extract solution. You can post your code by editing your question itself.

Comment: question edited ^^

Comment: wait for a while, I will work on it.

Comment: no Problem <3, thanks

Comment: Do you really want this behavior? Do you really need to switch your datacontext like this? I think your code smell... can't you use I don't know.... MVVM, or other stuff like this? it look like you are not following ANY wpf best practices. Do not try to hack something to make it work if it smell like this :p

Comment: i just dont know how to solve this in another way, even with MVVM. Ive read so much about MVVM and I still coulndt figure out how to Code it.

Comment: Why not use a tab control (with the header hidden) to pull up the tab (i.e. page) as needed using the selection? That way it's all loaded at once.

Comment: i have already tried that, worked perfectly fine until i wanted a viewmodel for each tabitem. man this is too hard for me.. :S

Comment: @pix so i coded the whole thing in mvvm but the Problem still is exactly the same. so to my question now: why did u mention it when it clearly wont solve my Problem.. just wasted time on it

Comment: @nairda-newb clean code is easier to work with, and see exactly what you want to achieve. So now you can update your question with the new code :)

Comment: @pix hey just wanted to say thank you, its so much more comfortable and it makes so much more fun to Code with mvvm. :)

Answer (score 0):

In `Mainwindow.xaml` Place the view in `stackpanel` to make `visiblity` hide show like this.

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="Page1Template" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:Page1Model}">
 <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Page1}">
  <views:Page1 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
 </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

In `MainWindow.xaml.cs` you have to set a property for visibility like this.

```
private Visibility page1;
public Visibility Page1
{
    get { return page1; }
    set { page1 = value; }
}
```

Then initialize the `DataContext` of each view in your `MainWindowLoad` function, so that it will be preloaded. After that you can set the visibility for the each view in your each menu click function like this:
`Page1 = Visibility.Visible;` or `Page1 = Visibility.Collapsed;` 
I hope it will works.

Comment: in theory this works but when i do this             DataContext = new Page1Model();
            DataContext = new Page2Model(); in my Window_Loaded function

it only takes the latest set DataContext and jsut Displays Page2. Am i initializing the DataContext correctly?

Comment: Add individual load for each view and refer the respective `Datacontext`

Comment: Like this `<views:Page1 DataContext="{Binding}" Loaded="Page1_Loaded"/>`

Comment: the Page1_Loaded function wont get triggered, why?